# Approximation of data in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector-layer

I have a problem in the section graduate( symbology--->graduate).
I want to scaling data from 0 to 0.9 in ten step, but when i put in the cases a range from 0.0 to 0.1 (or 0.1 to 0.2 etc)  the system  transforms the range from 0 to 1.000000 (or 1.000000 to 2.000000).

I have rinstalled the program and now  I have the 3.10, but I have the same problem. I have also tested my shape file in an another computer and the approximation works. What could be the problem?

Comment: if it work on another computer with the same data it could be a decimal separator problem, check the regional setting in your computer or try using comma as decimal separator

Comment: @Tomazic your edit add ArcGIS in the question title and tag but question body reference 3.10 and that's probably referring to latest QGIS release, are you sure about adding ArcGIS ?

Comment: @J.R You are right, it was just a guess. I'll remove it.